# How to include Date function in conditional argument

Tags: notepad++

I am attempting to edit an LST file in Notepad++. When the LST file is used with another program, it will generate a document. I have made several changes to the file so far, but keep getting an error whenever I attempt to create a conditional or if argument including the Today() function.

```
Align=0
Adjusted=False
Uneraseable=False
LineWrap=1
PageWrapAllowed=True
ForceWrap=True
SpaceOptimization=True
Spacing.Paragraph=0
Spacing.Line=0
OutputFormatter=DATE
[OutputFormatter.DATE]
 {
 DateFormatString=%02m/%02d/%y
 DateFormatType=0
 }
Condition=True
[ConditionalFormatter]
 {
 }
Text=cond(ReportData.IsAsFound,"Data", Today())
Tab=0
TabAlign=0
```

Comment: What is the question? It's really unclear what you want.

Comment: I think you are using Notepad++ to create some commands for another program, but you have not said what that program is.